# Pushing to a remote with basic authentication

Tags: go, go-git

I'm currently struggling to get go-git working with private repositories on GitHub. Although working with the git command line works as expected (`git push origin`), the code snippet below does not work. The last log command returns the following result:

```
 Error during push     error=repository not found
```

The repository itself does exist, otherwise the push from the command line would not work. First, I thought, that it might be related that the remote repository is empty. But even if that's not the case, I've got the same error. The credentials are valid, I've double-checked them.

So, there must be something I am missing. But since I am new to Go, my expertise is too low for this to be figured out.

```golang
package git

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"

    "github.com/apex/log"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/config"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/object"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

const gitDataDirectory = "./data/"
const defaultRemoteName = "origin"

// Commit creates a commit in the current repository
func Commit() {
    repo, err := git.PlainOpen(gitDataDirectory)

    if err != nil {
        // Repository does not exist yet, create it
        log.Info("The Git repository does not exist yet and will be created.")

        repo, err = git.PlainInit(gitDataDirectory, false)
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("The data folder could not be converted into a Git repository. Therefore, the versioning does not work as expected.")
        return
    }

    w, _ := repo.Worktree()


    log.Info("Committing new changes...")
    w.Add(".gitignore")
    w.Add("info.json")
    w.Commit("test", &git.CommitOptions{
        Author: &object.Signature{
            Name:  "test",
            Email: "test@localhost",
            When:  time.Now(),
        },
    })

    _, err = repo.Remote(defaultRemoteName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Info("Creating new Git remote named " + defaultRemoteName)
        _, err = repo.CreateRemote(&config.RemoteConfig{
            Name: defaultRemoteName,
            URLs: []string{"https://github.com/jlnostr/blub.git"},
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Warn("Error creating remote")
        }
    }

    auth := &http.BasicAuth{
        Username: "jlnostr",
        Password: "[git_basic_auth_token]",
    }
    log.Info("Pushing changes to remote")
    err = repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        RemoteName: defaultRemoteName,
        Auth:       auth,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Warn("Error during push")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues:

1. The GitHub token only had access to public repositories, but I've tried to push to a private repository. Using the `repo` permissions (instead of just `repo:public`) helped.
2. The repo was not yet "really" initialized. Pulling before pushing helped in this case, as @peakle mentioned.

So, below is a complete working example for initializing a private repository with go-git v5.

```golang
package git

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/config"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/object"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
)

const gitDataDirectory = "./data/"
const defaultRemoteName = "origin"

var auth = &http.BasicAuth{
    Username: "<username>",
    Password: "<git_basic_auth_token>",
}

func createCommitOptions() *git.CommitOptions {
    return &git.CommitOptions{
        Author: &object.Signature{
            Name:  "Rick Astley",
            Email: "never.gonna.give.you.up@localhost",
            When:  time.Now(),
        },
    }
}

// Commit creates a commit in the current repository
func Commit() {
    err := initializeGitRepository()
    if err != nil {
        // logging: The folder could not be converted into a Git repository.
        return
    }

    // Open after initialization
    repo, _ := git.PlainOpen(gitDataDirectory)
    w, _ := repo.Worktree()

    status, _ := w.Status()
    if status.IsClean() {
        return
    }

    // Committing new changes
    w.Add("<your_file>.txt")
    w.Commit("test", createCommitOptions())

    // Pushing to remote
    err = repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        RemoteName: defaultRemoteName,
        Auth:       auth,
    })
}

func initializeGitRepository() error {
    _, err := git.PlainOpen(gitDataDirectory)
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }

    // The Git repository does not exist yet and will be created.

    repo, err := git.PlainInit(gitDataDirectory, false)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Writing default .gitignore with "media/" as first line
    filename := filepath.Join(gitDataDirectory, ".gitignore")
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, []byte("media/"), 0644)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    w, _ := repo.Worktree()
    w.Add(".gitignore")
    w.Commit("Initial commit", createCommitOptions())

    return initializeRemote()
}

func initializeRemote() error {
    repo, err := git.PlainOpen(gitDataDirectory)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = repo.Remote(defaultRemoteName)
    if err == nil {
        // Repo already exists, skipping
        return nil
    }

    w, err := repo.Worktree()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    refspec := config.RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*")

    // Creating default remote
    _, err = repo.CreateRemote(&config.RemoteConfig{
        Name:  defaultRemoteName,
        URLs:  []string{"https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"},
        Fetch: []config.RefSpec{refspec},
    })

    if err != nil {
        // TODO
    }

    // Pulling from remote
    w.Pull(&git.PullOptions{
        RemoteName: defaultRemoteName,
        Auth:       auth,
    })

    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code few times with minimal changes like below and it work fine on case when repo also clonned and git inited, commit message to approve: https://github.com/peakle/iptables-http-services/commit/56eba2fcc4fac790ad573942ab1b926ddadf0875

i can't reproduce your problem but maybe it can help you with git error that occurred on your case: https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/error-repository-not-found , i think you have typo on repo name or something similar to cases described in link above.

and additional for future enhancements to your codebase , i have problems on case when git not yet inited, i add some code and TODO block with recommendations maybe it can help you in future :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    _ "path/filepath"
    "time"

    "github.com/apex/log"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/config"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/object"
    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
)

const gitDataDirectory = "/Users/peakle/projects/tests/iptables-http-services"
const defaultRemoteName = "origin"

func main() {
    filename := "kek.txt"
    file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", gitDataDirectory, filename))
    _, _ = file.Write([]byte("test string2"))
    Commit(filename)
}

// Commit creates a commit in the current repository
func Commit(filename string) {
    var isNewInit bool
    repo, err := git.PlainOpen(gitDataDirectory)

    if err != nil {
        // Repository does not exist yet, create it
        log.Info("The Git repository does not exist yet and will be created.")

        repo, err = git.PlainInit(gitDataDirectory, false)
        isNewInit = true
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("The data folder could not be converted into a Git repository. Therefore, the versioning does not work as expected.")
        return
    }

    w, _ := repo.Worktree()

    log.Info("Committing new changes...")
    if isNewInit {
        err = w.AddGlob("*")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        //TODO if its new git init, need to add `git pull` command  with remote branch
    } else {
        _, _ = w.Add(filename)
    }

    _, _ = w.Commit("test", &git.CommitOptions{
        Author: &object.Signature{
            Name:  "peakle",
            Email: "test@mail.com",
            When:  time.Now(),
        },
    })

    _, err = repo.Remote(defaultRemoteName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Info("Creating new Git remote named " + defaultRemoteName)
        _, err = repo.CreateRemote(&config.RemoteConfig{
            Name: defaultRemoteName,
            URLs: []string{"https://github.com/Peakle/iptables-http-services.git"},
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Warn("Error creating remote")
        }
    }

    auth := &http.BasicAuth{
        Username: "peakle",
        Password: "authtoken",
    }

    log.Info("Pushing changes to remote")
    err = repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        RemoteName: defaultRemoteName,
        Auth:       auth,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Warn("Error during push")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've pointed me in the right direction. I've adapted some of your changes and created a answer with my mistakes. :)

Comment: @jlnostr im very happy to hear that:)